# Can I use or condition on When into a trigger?

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger on oracle database and i'm having troubles with when condition.
When i try to use it i get "invalid relational operator"

```
   create or replace TRIGGER SQLTEST.TRIGGER_TESTE
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON SQLDBA.VT_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (INSERTING OR NEW.FIELD_1 is null and OLD.FIELD_1 is not null or NEW.FIELD_1 <> OLD.FIELD_1) 

DECLARE
VAR_FIELD_1 VT_LOG_TABLE.FIELD_1%TYPE;

BEGIN

SELECT SQLDBA.SEQ_LOG_TABLE.NEXtval into VAR_FIELD_1
FROM dual;


INSERT INTO VT_LOG_TABLE
(FIELD_0,VAR_FIELD_1,FIELD_2,FIELD_3,FIELD_1, FIELD_4 )
VALUES( :NEW.FIELD_0,VAR_FIELD_1, :NEW.FIELD_2, :NEW.FIELD_3, :NEW.FIELD_1,SYSDATE);

END TRIGGER_TESTE;
```

What's the right way to make that condition?

Comment: Can you post the whole trigger?

Comment: create or replace TRIGGER SQLTEST.TRIGGER_TESTE
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON SQLDBA.VT_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (INSERTING OR NEW.FIELD_1 is null and OLD.FIELD_1 is not null or NEW.FIELD_1 <> OLD.FIELD_1) 

DECLARE
VAR_FIELD_1 VT_LOG_TABLE.FIELD_1%TYPE;

BEGIN

SELECT SQLDBA.SEQ_LOG_TABLE.NEXtval into VAR_FIELD_1
FROM dual;


INSERT INTO VT_LOG_TABLE
(FIELD_0,VAR_FIELD_1,FIELD_2,FIELD_3,FIELD_1, FIELD_4 )
VALUES( :NEW.FIELD_0,VAR_FIELD_1, :NEW.FIELD_2, :NEW.FIELD_3, :NEW.FIELD_1,SYSDATE);

END TRIGGER_TESTE;

Comment: The error could be the `NEW.FIELD_1 <> OLD.FIELD_1` because when inserting you don't have the OLD for comparison... but not 100% sure about this.

Answer (score 3):

As graceemile says, the `WHEN` clause doesn't understand `INSERTING`. I'm not sure if you can rely on `old.field_1 is null` to indicate an insert since it looks like a nullable field (since `new.field_1` can apparently be null). If you can't then you could just move the logic into the block:

```
create or replace trigger vt_trigger
after insert or update on vt_table
for each row
declare
    do_logging boolean := false;
begin
    if inserting then
        do_logging := true;
    elsif (:new.field_1 is null and :old.field_1 is not null)
        or (:new.field_1 is not null and :old.field_1 is null)
        or (:new.field_1 <> :old.field_1)
    then
        do_logging := true;
    end if;

    if do_logging then
        insert into vt_log_table (field_0, var_field_1, field_2, field_3,
            field_1, field_4)
        values (:new.field_0, seq_log_table.nextval, :new.field_2, :new.field_3,
            :new.field_1, sysdate);
    end if;
end vt_trigger;
/
```

I've changed the check a bit to this:

```
    elsif (:new.field_1 is null and :old.field_1 is not null)
        or (:new.field_1 is not null and :old.field_1 is null)
        or (:new.field_1 <> :old.field_1)
```

... to detect if `field_1` has changed from null, to null, or from one non-null value to another; maybe you don't want that, the partial check just looked a bit odd to me. I'm assuming you only want to log if `field_1` has changed in any way, or if you're inserting a new row of course.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried something similar and Oracle doesn't like the INSERTING value in the WHEN condition. It appears to be OK with NEW and OLD, even if inserting.

From experimentation, it looks like your trigger will fire on INSERTS if you add this to your WHEN condition:

```
OR OLD.FIELD_1 IS NULL
```

So try something like this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER SQLTEST.TRIGGER_TESTE
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON SQLDBA.VT_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.FIELD_1 is null and OLD.FIELD_1 is not null
   or NEW.FIELD_1 <> OLD.FIELD_1
   or OLD.FIELD_1 IS NULL)

DECLARE

... and so on
```

If that gets too complicated, you can create two triggers: one for UPDATE with the WHEN condition and one for INSERT, without conditions.

You could also try defining the trigger as AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF Field_1 ON VT_TABLE:

```
create or replace trigger vt_trigger
after insert or update of field_1 on vt_table
for each row
begin
    insert into vt_log_table (field_0, var_field_1, field_2, field_3,
        field_1, field_4)
    values (:new.field_0, seq_log_table.nextval, :new.field_2, :new.field_3,
        :new.field_1, sysdate);
end vt_trigger;
/
```

Comment: if "OLD.FIELD_1 is null" it means that im inserting a new row, right?

Comment: Is that a valid inference though? The `NEW.FIELD_1 is null` suggests the field is nullable. If it is null and you set it to not-null then it'll fire, which I think you want - though that isn't covered in the question; but if it's null and you leave it null while updating other fields it will also fire, won't it?

Comment: Good point Alex. @Igor: it just occurred to me that you could also try defining the trigger as `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF Field_1 ON VT_TABLE`. I haven't used this type of definition before, but if I'm reading the docs right it will fire on (1) any INSERT and (2) on any UPDATE that changes Field_1. I'm a bit pressed for time so I'll have to leave it to you to experiment if you think this approach is worth trying.

Comment: Of course you can... that's so much cleaner than my hack. (Still assuming any null/not-null change should be captured). I've added an example to your answer, hope that's OK. Shame I can't up-vote again...